# How to access bean from another context

Tags: java, spring

I want to access a Spring bean which has been autowired in a separate context.

Is this possible ?

I think I can use the ApplicationContext and wire it using something like this :

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext ctx = null;
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
    }
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}


<bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>
```

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you are doing is making a listener for the current context you declare your bean in.

> I want to access a Spring bean which has been autowired in a separate
>   context.

If you need to do some autowiring, you'll need to import the other context with `<import>` or `@Import` depending on your configuration type (java vs xml). For example

```
<import resource="classpath:/path/to/otherAppContext.xml" />
```

If you just want to get a bean, you can always create the other `ApplicationContext` and `getBean()`.

```
ApplicationContext otherContext = ...// get other context  
BeanClass otherBean = otherContext.getBean(BeanClass.class);
```

You can also merge application contexts in the same fashion as the `ContextLoaderListener` does with the `DispatcherServlet`. Take a look at the source code for more details.